# closing a loaded SWF file without closing the whole application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm loading an SWF file into my main app (a flash desktop app), and i want to be able to close it using an exit button without closing the whole app.

i've tried

```
import flash.system.fscommand;

exitButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
      fscommand("quit");
 }
```

i'm putting this code in the loaded SWF file, instead of closing it alone, it closes the whole window.
Any idea how can i close the loaded SWF while remaining in my main app?

Comment: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#unloadAndStop()

Comment: I have 2 SWF files, one named Main and the other named Movie, they have both the same size 1280x800, so, when i load Movie into Main it covers the whole Main screen, so i decided to put the exitButton in the Movie SWF file, the problem now is that the loader object is in the Main file, so i can't use the unloadAndStop() method in the Movie file.

Comment: Loader instance is the parent of the root of the loaded SWF.

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't understand your last comment.

Comment: **Loader** is a **DisplayObjectContainer** that holds the loaded SWF as a child. So the whole hierarchy goes like *stage -> Main root -> ... whatever -> Loader -> Movie root*. Thus, if you put **trace(parent)** into the Movie main timeline, it will output something like [object Loader].